# Función JavaScript no es ejecutada desde el navegador en los dispositivos moviles

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, android, google-chrome

Actualmente tengo un input tipo texto, como el siguiente:
`<input class="form-control" type="text" id="IdUser">`
y tengo la siguiente función para que se ejecuté apenas se cargue la pagina

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#IdUser").val(getCookie('_ga'))},1000,"JavaScript");
  });
```

Cuando navego desde mi PC la función se ejecuta normal, pero cuando ingreso desde un navegador en mi celular el campo queda vacío, que puedo hacer para que esto no siga sucediendo?